# 標準入力の値を abs() に渡すとエラー: bad operand type for abs(): 'str'

Tags: python

`-2` を入力したら `2` と出るように絶対値を表示するようにしたいのですが以下のエラーが出ます。どうしたらよいでしょうか？

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
bad operand type for abs(): 'str'
```

**ソースコード:**

```
n_string=input('整数を入力: ')

n=abs(n_string)

print(n)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
n_int=int(n_string)
n=abs(n_int)
```